# twig renders number field as text

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

In my form class I added number field:

```
$builder->add('total_amount', 'number', array('required' => false));
```

In my form template:

```
{{ form_widget(form.total_amount, {'attr': {'class': 'field number_field'}}) }}
```

However, my page source shows:

```
<input type="text" id="ResearchDataForm_total_amount" 
    name="ResearchDataForm[total_amount]" class="field number_field" value="0" />
```

I expected type="number", but it is rendered as type="text". Why so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There actually two options in symfony forms one is integer and other is number. Number is mainly used for decimal point values. Whereas integer is just for whole numbers. If you want whole numbers go with integer it has option to automatically rounded up numbers.

Before you  do check this link
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/integer.html

The input type number is something i personally don't prefer because its has been implemented only by few browsers and you would want things to look similar across all browsers. These things will actually might even confuse general users.

Answer (score 0):

The fields of type number are displayed like this (type="text"), do not worry, because if the user enters something that is not a number, it will fail:

```
This value is not valid.
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#text-fields

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/number.html